# TypeError: Cannot read property '****' of undefined in Angular project when using inside forEach

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript, typeerror

When i am trying to loop through **this.data.members** and do some action inside forEach on **this.addedUsers** i am getting **TypeError: Cannot read property 'addedUsers' of undefined**. I am able to access **this.data.members** outside the foarEach.

```
export class AddgroupComponent implements OnInit {
public addedUsers: any[] = [];

constructor(
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any
    ) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
       this.data.members.forEach(function (item) {
        console.log(this.addedUsers)
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `this` inside JS `function` refers to the scope of the function. Use either arrow function `this.data.members.forEach(item =>  {...` or [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) function to refer to the class member variables.

Comment: Thanks for the reply..Using the first arrow function technique worked @MichaelD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are trying to access `this` context inside **forEach** with ES5 syntax which is `function (item)`, `this` will be undefined due to [laxical scoping](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/10/20/javascript-scope-closures/).  To access `this`, you have to use **arrow function** `() => {}` ES6 feature.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
       this.data.members.forEach((item) => {     // use of () => { ... }arrow function
        

        // probably you want to push members
        // this.addedUsers.push(item) ;

         console.log(this.addedUsers)

      });
    }
}
```